# Use pathfinding algorithm in a navmesh with several endpoints

Tags: path-finding

I need to implement a pathfinding algorithm in a navmesh with several endpoints, and I would like to find the path to the closest endpoint. I suppose that Dijkstra algorithm is the best solution for that but it needs some adaptation. Is someone could help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a massive change, just instead of `current_node == destination` it will be `destination_set.contains(current_node)`.

Otherwise you can reverse the search, go from the endpoints to the start.

That way you can use A* (given a proper heuristic). You just need to start with all endpoints in the starting set.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I suppose A* will be perhaps more efficient if I have  a few endpoints, and Dijkstra will be best if my destination is near the startpoint (and more endpoints), right ?

Comment: That contains check can be done in constant time (HashSet or marking the node as destination in its metadata) However starting from the endpoints you will select the closest (according to heuristic) endpoint first to expand. It's not different as if you had a "teleport" from a imaginary starting node.